# Authorize or can methods always return false for laravel policy

Tags: php, laravel, authorization, policy, voyager

I'm having trouble setting up policy in Laravel. I'm using Laravel voyager admin panel that comes integrated with Laravel policy concept. I have created policy for content model and assigned it to Content BREAD. Just to check the result, I simply returned true in view function. And yet, it still returns false.

Here is a snippet from ContentPolicy class:

```
    /*
     * Determine whether the user can view the content.
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $user
     * @param  \App\Content  $content
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function view(User $user, Content $content)
    {
        return true;
    }
```

and here in ContentController:

```
    public function view(Request $request)
    {
        $content=Content::all();

        return var_dump($this->authorize("view",$content));
    }
```

and here I registered my policy

```
class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The policy mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $policies = [
        'App\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
        Content::class => ContentPolicy::class

    ];

    /**
     * Register any authentication / authorization services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();
        Passport::routes();

        //
    }
}
```

It is worth to note that 'browse_admin' works fine in such case for laravel voyager.

I appreciate your help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you added your policy in your `AuthServiceProvider`? Check the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authorization#registering-policies).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I did and it did not work

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authorization#creating-policies) you should register your policies in `AuthServiceProvider` like this:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Content;
use App\Policies\ContentPolicy;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The policy mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $policies = [
        Content::class => ContentPolicy::class,
    ];

    /**
     * Register any application authentication / authorization services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();

        //
    }
}
```

Comment: are you trying with the authenticated user? By default, all gates and policies automatically return false if the incoming HTTP request was not initiated by an authenticated user.

Comment: Yes I do with authenticated user, it works with 'browse_admin" permission but not with self created policies

Answer (score 0):

Have you put `before` method in your policy?if yes please remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and fixed it, you need to add this to your policy at this is what Voyager checks.

```
    public function browse(){
        return true;
    }
    
    public function add(){
        return true;
    }

    public function delete(){
        return true;
    }

    public function edit(){
        return true;
    }

    public function read(){
        return true;
    }
```